# How to apply an async operation on list view builder?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get set of encrypted data documents from firebase and display them on a list view on flutter.

I used a stream builder for obtaining data and started displaying it on the list view. But I cant perform the decryption operation on each data item as it is an async operation. What is the  best way to do this?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection(ScopedModel.of<User>(context).userId)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');

                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Center(
                        child: new Container(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ));
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Empty',),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                    final docs = snapshot.data.documents;

                    return ScrollConfiguration(
                      behavior: ScrollBehavior(),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: len,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, position) {

                                  // Where should I decrypt the below data?
                                  // let decrypted = await myDecryptionFunction(docs[position]['myDataKey']) ;
                                  // the above is not working

                                  // this will show the encrypted text
                                  return Text(docs[position]['myDataKey']);
                        }




      ....
```

Comment: It can be when you are assigning the `stream` on this part `Firestore.instance
                  .collection(ScopedModel.of<User>(context).userId)
                  .snapshots()`, so you should get the documents already decrypted on the builder method

Comment: Is it possible to modify the original stream coming from Firebase? I'm totally new to this stream programming. @Hosar

Answer (score 1):

For your situation you can use a **StreamController** with a helper class to hold the information.
The following is just an example but adapt it to your own needs.

```
// Helper classes
// adapt it to your own business case
class Notes {
  String title;
  String description;

  Notes({this.title, this.description});
}

class NotesFromDb {
  String connectionState;
  bool hasError;
  String error;
  List<Notes> notes;
  NotesFromDb({this.connectionState, this.hasError, this.error, this.notes});
}

// The Streambuilder
StreamBuilder<NotesFromDb>(
  stream: sController.stream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<NotesFromDb> snapshot) {
    // Here you can check for errors
    if (snapshot.data.hasError == true) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(snapshot.data.error),
      );
    }
    // Here you can check for your connection state
    if (snapshot.data.connectionState == 'Loading') {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    // Here you can show your data
    var info = snapshot.data.notes.map((doc) {
      return Text(doc.title);
    });

    return Center(
        child: Container(
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
      child: Column(
        children: info.toList(),
      ),
    ));
  })

// Here is how you can handle the decrypt data
// using a FloatingActionButton for loading the data (for example)
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async { // you would need to add the async

    List<Notes> theNotes; //just to hold the information
    // Use this to allow to show the CircularProgressIndicator
    sController.sink.add(NotesFromDb(connectionState: 'Loading'));

    var snapshots = Firestore.instance.collection('notes').snapshots();
    snapshots.listen((QuerySnapshot data) {
      theNotes = data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        // Build your data
        return Notes(
            title: doc.data['title'],
            description: doc.data['description']);
      }).toList();
    }, onError: (err, stack) {
      // If an error happend then send the error to the stream
      sController.sink
          .add(NotesFromDb(hasError: true, error: err.error));
    });

    // Here you can to decrypt the documents with your function
    var decryptDocuments = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); //Whatever future function

    // Once you have the decrypt documents, you would need to send that to the stream.
    // set the connectionState to Done, so the spinner is not showed anymore.
    sController.sink.add(NotesFromDb(
        hasError: false, connectionState: 'Done', notes: decryptDocuments));
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
)
```

Take the example just for illustration  on how to do it.
Hope this help.